# How to install the iPhone application on my iPod touch

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

My technical director just send me the provisioning file and the certificate, so now i have two files, and i try to google how can i install my application on my iPod touch to test it. could you please explain me or may be step-by-step articles could help, thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, add certificate to Keychain Access (Applications - Utilities) in section "login". After that drag and drop provisioning profiles to Xcode, it will add them to Organizer.
After that, if your device is added to this profiles you can connect ur device to usb cable and choose Target SDK for supported by your device. Finally, Run application from Xcode.
If you will obtain sign error - change code sign option to your certificate name from Xcode / Build settings.