# How to provision my iOS device for development?

Tags: iphone, ios, provisioning

I have the following files with me.

aps_dev_cert_key.p12
aps_developer_identity.cer
and 
apxxx_dev.mobileprovision

Same set exists for distribution too. Now, I went to Keychain access, dragged key file onto "Keys" and cer file onto "Certificates". I followed the instruction in this post
[How to install the iPhone application on my iPod touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663787/how-to-install-the-iphone-application-on-my-ipod-touch)

But Build & Run is not working for me, as I get "The Identity xxxxyyyyzzzzzxxxxx doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in default keychain"

Comment: What app-id did you use to create the provisioning profile? It should match the id in your Info.plist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Double click the "aps_dev_cert_key.p12", it should be password protected. Enter password, it will automatically install the cert and key to KeyChain.
2. Double click the "apxxx_dev.mobileprovision", it should be automatically installed to xCode, which can be viewed in Organizer.
3. Open Settings for your project>> Code sign: select the cert that was just added.
4. Build to Device should install it to your iphone, provided the Iphone's UDID was added in the "apxxx_dev.mobileprovision".

hope that helps.

Comment: *help that helps*? Pretty self-confident, aren't you? ;)

Comment: Thank you very much! I removed every other profile and followed your steps and it worked perfectly. Sadly, I use a 2g iPod touch and I am not able to port my app now since the iOS I use is 4.2.1 :-(..